# NSView mouseEntered/mouseMoved not called during dragging operation (and vice versa)

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsview

I have a borderless window with a transparent `NSView`. When the mouse cursor enters the transparent view, a second view (the drop target) is supposed to appear allowing the user to drop a file.

The problem is that `draggingEntered:` is not called while dragging a file over the *transparent view* (so the drop target view never appears).

The transparent view has a tracking area correctly set up. When not dragging a file (i.e. normal mouse movements), the transparent view fires correctly for `mouseEntered:` and `mouseMoved:` events.

Seems like a chicken-and-egg problem:

Either I need `draggingEntered:` to fire for the transparent view or I need `mouseEntered:` to be called while dragging a file to show the drop target view.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the transparent view for dragging via `registerForDraggedTypes:`. Then your view will receive the drag/drop methods.

You don't need to support drag/drop there (return `NO` when asked if the drag-operation is supported), but you'll get the drag/drop events.