# NSView: mouseMoved(with:) not called when dragging

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsview

As the title suggests, I am having an issue where mouseMoved isn't being called when dragging another view. I have set the tracking area and it is called when not dragging. Also, `mouseEntered(with:)` is still called when dragging.

Is there any way to make it so that `mouseMoved` (/any other event) is still called on a drag event?

I've seen [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154881/nsview-mouseentered-mousemoved-not-called-during-dragging-operation-and-vice-ve) from a few years ago, but none I found had answers.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried implementing `mouseDragged(with:)` and see if that event is being delivered?

Comment: Yes—it is not called (since the dragging event did not begin in the view).

Comment: How are the views related?

Comment: the dragged view and the view that I would like to call `mouseMoved(with:)` on are both members of the same superview. While this makes it possible to get a similar event call, the user can (and will most likely) add thousands of views, thus checking if the mouse coordinates are bounded by each of its subviews is too inefficient.

Comment: How is dragging another view implemented? Post a [mre] please.